# Using Gradle to build IntelliJ Plugins

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, intellij-plugin

I am working on developing plugins for IntelliJ. I would like to be able to build the plugin using Gradle. I would also love to use the dependency management in Gradle to sync my plugin project in IntelliJ.

I have tried searching, but all of the keywords are pretty ambigious (intellij, plugin, gradle, etc). I get posts on using the Gradle plugin in IntelliJ and posts on using the IntelliJ plugin in Gradle... :)

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Is it the "Prepare plugin module for deployment" feature that you want to automate via gradle?

Comment: Yes, that is one action. The other would be "Sync project with Gradle" feature that would download and add dependencies to the project.

Comment: Let me know if there is any movement on this question, or if you've figured it out.  I'm trying to do the same thing.

Comment: Nada. Nothing that I've come up with.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it is still relevant, but here is the corresponding plugin: https://github.com/JetBrains/gradle-intellij-plugin